# CSS: adjusting checkbox size

Tags: css, checkbox

Is there a way to adjust the dimension of an `<input type="checkbox" />`

I already tried it using `style="width:30px; height:50px;"` approach, but it didn't work.
Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, i don't think there's a way of doing it by only using html / css.

You could just make an overlay (div) which is positioned right over the checkbox and makes it visible. Using this overlay you could add an own checkbox graphic and change it's image (=it's **visible value**) whenever the user clicks on the image. Furhtermore you'll then have to update the real checkbox's value manually to assure that the form can be send containing the checkbox's **form value**.

This technique is often used by RIA frameworks like QooxDoo, ExtJS, etc.

[here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) you'll find a really nice example of how to use the described technique.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible.

You can change the size of a checkbox using the [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale) function of the [transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/) CSS property, which can magnify or shrink the check box.

Firefox 16.0+ and Internet Explorer 10.0+ support direct invocation of the transform property while older versions and Webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari) require their own prefixes ([more on browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)).

Simple example:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
    transform: scale(2);         /* FF 16+, IE 10+ */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Chrome, Safari 3.5+, Opera 15+ */

    -ms-transform: scale(2);     /* legacy: IE 9+ */
    -moz-transform: scale(2);    /* legacy: FF 3.5+ */
    -o-transform: scale(2);      /* legacy: Opera 10.5 */
  }
</style>

...

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```