# how change checkbox webview android

Tags: android, checkbox, webview

I have android app where load webView.
On webview I have checkbox but don't can change size.

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

screen
http://postimg.org/image/l9lg35czj/

change size

```
input[type="checkbox"]
    {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
    }
```

http://postimg.org/image/v96ow0otv/

why size not changed on webview, (if I look this page with browser checkbox size changed)?

full code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .single_user
    {
        width:100%;
        height:120px;
        border: black;
        background:#E5E5E5;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .user_image 
    {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    h1
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]
    {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="single_user">
<img class="user_image" src="statimg/profileicon.png"/>
<h1> Vahagn Vard2anyan <br />
vvvaagn@gmail.com</h1>
<input type="checkbox" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"/>
</div>
<div class="single_user">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is proper looking to me.
Can u post full code here?
It also does depends upon the device and os version of android.
on which device u r ruuning your app on and on which android os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with this problem too. Checkboxes in html initially doesn't change its size by width/height CSS properties (but some browsers support this). If you want to change size, you can use `transform: scale(scaleX, scaleY);` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911993/css-adjusting-checkbox-size))or you can implement custom checkboxes like [this](http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp), but it will be trick.

**UPDATE**

Checkbox can be easy resplaced by span with text and click event handler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #checkbox {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background: red;
        }
        #checkmark {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            font-size:30px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setCheckboxChecked(checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        var checkmark = checkbox.querySelector('#checkmark');
        if(checkbox.checked) {
            checkmark.innerHTML = '\u2713';
        } else {
            checkmark.innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setCheckboxChecked(this);">
    <span id="checkmark"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but don't help this

Comment: If it helps you, set the answer is accepted and/or vote up it.